# How to end a thread properly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

My main program creates a thread. This thread initializes some data then enters a 'while' loop and runs until the main program sets the control variable to 'false'. Then it calls join() witch blocks the whole code endlessly.

```
bool m_ThreadMayRun;

void main(){
   thread mythread = thread(&ThreadFunction);
   //do stuff
   m_ThreadMayRun = false;
   mythread.join(); // this blocks endlessly even when I ask 'joinable' before
}

void ThreadFunction{
   initdata();
   m_ThreadMayRun=true;
   while(m_ThreadMayRun){
   //do stuff that can be / has to be done for ever
   }
   deinitdata();
}
```

- Am I missing something here?
- What would be a proper solution to make the loop leave from the main thread?
- Is it at all necessary to call join?

Thanks for help

Comment: As you've seen `joinable()` doesn't help here. The thread **is** joinable; you created it that way. (Incidentally, creating the thread could (and should) have been done with `thread my thread(&ThreadFunction)`)

Answer (score 2):

You have a race condition for two threads writing to `m_ThreadMayRun`. Consider what happens if first the main thread executes `m_ThreadMayRun = false;` and then the thread you spwaned executes `m_ThreadMayRun = true;`, then you have an infinite loop. However, strictly speaking that line of reasoning is irrelevant, because when you have a race condition your code has undefined behavior.

> Am I missing something here?

You need to synchronize access to `m_ThreadMayRun` by making it either an `std::atomic<bool>` or using a `std::mutex` and make sure that `m_ThreadMayRun = false` is executed after `m_ThreadMayRun = true;`.

**PS** For this situation it is better to use a `std::condition_variable`.

Comment: it's better to use condvar here to make sure that `m_ThreadMayRun = true` is executed after `m_ThreadMayRun=false`

Comment: @user3365922 indeed, I wanted to keep it simple, but I will add a note

Comment: Setting the control variable to true in the main thread is  a clear and understandable style improvement. But after this, since the thread is only reading the variable, I do not see the race condition. Am I blind? But if 'atomic' is the key, I am happy with this solution.

Comment: @M.Enke there is `m_ThreadMayRun=true;` in the function called from the thread in your code. Even if the thread would only read it would be problematic. You have a race condition when two threads access the same memory and at least one writes to it

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that access to `bool m_ThreadMayRun;` is not synchronized, and according to C++ rules, each thread may assume it does not change between threads. So you end up with a race (a form of undefined behavior).

To make the intention clear, make it `atomic`.

```
std::atomic<bool> m_ThreadMayRun;
```

With this every load/store of `m_ThreadMayRun` becomes a memory fence, which not only synchronizes its own value, but also makes *other work* done by the thread visible, due to the acquire/release semantics of an atomic load/store.

Though there is still a small race possible between `m_ThreadMayRun = true` in the thread and setting `m_ThreadMayRun = false`. Either one can execute first, sometimes leading to undesired results. To avoid this, initialize it to `true` *before* starting the thread.

```
std::atomic<bool> m_ThreadMayRun;

void main(){
   m_ThreadMayRun = true;
   thread mythread(&ThreadFunction);
   //do stuff
   m_ThreadMayRun = false;
   mythread.join(); // this blocks endlessly even when I ask 'joinable' before
}

void ThreadFunction{
   initdata();
   while(m_ThreadMayRun){
   //do stuff that can be / has to be done for ever
   }
   deinitdata();
}
```

For more details about memory fences and acquire/release semantics, refer to the following excellent resources: the book "*C++ Concurrency in Action*" and Herb Sutter's [`atomic<>` weapons](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2) talk.